# Splitting an Azure pipeline into stages

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'd like to split my pipeline into stages: restore, build, test, pack, publish, (and maybe even deploy -- don't understand that).

At present the build stage doesn't restore because that's already been done.
Similarly, the test stage doesn't restore or build, and nor do pack or publish.

However, if I split this into stages then I seem to have to restore and build separately in every stage.

Is there a way to get one stage to feed into the next like tasks do?

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid this approach.

The way pipelines work is divided in to a hierarchy as a way of grouping tasks together

```
Stages
  Jobs
    Tasks
```

- Stages by default run in sequence, but you can override this
  behaviour
- Jobs by default run in parallel within the scope of the stage, but
  you can override this behaviour
- Tasks are always run in sequence within the scope of a job

So in your approach where you split out each task of your build in to a separate stage there is an intermediate job.

Jobs are usually independent of one another. If you have multiple jobs in a stage, by default they will run in parallel and extra work will need to be done to make an explicit dependency and to pass the results of one job to another. If you have multiple build agents, jobs may run on different agents.

For a "build" this is unnecessary and will make your process more complex than it needs to be. If you split it out the way you've suggested then your process will end up something like

My definition of a build is "a process that produces tested and packaged output" rather than "code is compiled"

```
Stage: Restore
  Job: Restore
    Task: Restore
    Task: Package up restored things
    Task: Upload package
Stage: Build
  Job: Build
    Task: Download package from previous stage / job (this is effectively just doing another restore)
    Task: Build
    Task: package up build output
Stage: Test
  Job: Test
    Task: Download build output
    Task: run tests
    Task: Publish test results
Stage: pack
  Job: pack
    Task: download build output
    Task: package build output (we've already had to do this)
    Task: Publish build output (and this)
Stage: publish
  Job: publish
    Task: download build output
    Task: package build output (we've already had to do this twice now)
    Task: Publish build output (and this)
```

It's much simpler to do your entire build process in a single job and stage

```
Stage: Build
  Job: Build
    Task: Restore
    Task: Build
    Task: run tests
    Task: Publish test output
    Task: Package code
    Task: Publish build output
```

Stages should be used to define the overall orchestration of your pipeline, so something like

Build -> Deploy to Dev -> Deploy to QA -> Deploy to staging -> Deploy to Prod

Within each stage you might have multiple jobs that can run in parallel

```
Stage: Build
  Job: Build for x86
    Task: ...
  Job: Build for ARM
    Task: ...
```

or

```
Stage: Deploy to Dev
  Job: Deploy database
    Task: ...
  Job: Deploy web site
    Task: ...
  Job: Deploy web service
    Task: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Click the Pre-deployment Conditions icon (little dude and lightning bolt) on the stage and select the After Stage condition like this:
[image]

Then that stage will only execute its tasks after the first stage is complete, and so on.

After that, you can independently deploy each stage or have them chain from the beginning.

Comment: I'm using yml.
There is no problem getting the stages to run in sequence.
The problem is that the workspace appears to get wiped in between stages so for example the test stage doesn't have the build and therefore has to build from scratch again -- which is a waste of time.

If I have just 1 stage with 1 job and lots of steps then it works, but splitting it up doesn't work.

Comment: Are you uploading the artifacts into devops after you build them? If you are, you should be able to add them to the next stage in the pipeline and it will download them to a working folder before the stage runs.